# how to submit checkbox value in angular

Tags: html, angular

for getCities(), i am fetching data from api, 
which i just showed in li tag, i am in deliama how to submit the check box value,

when customer will check for multiple cities

```
 <form #hlForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="filterData(hlForm)">
   <span>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-blue" (click)="getCities()">Select City</button>
    <ul class="location-filter" *ngIf="cityList">
     <li *ngFor="let city of cityList">
       {{city}} <input type="checkbox" name="selectCity">
     </li>
   </ul>
  </span>
 <button type="submit" value="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using template driven forms, add `NgModel` to the element attributes.

You should also add a unique name to each `li` element to be able to differentiate between values:

```
 <li *ngFor="let city of cityList">
   {{city.name}} <input type="checkbox" [name]="city.name" ngModel>
 </li>
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpqgfv?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an array where you can store all your selected cities, and update this array each time a checkbox for a city is checked/unchecked.

Change your code to:

```
 <form #hlForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="filterData(hlForm)">
   <span>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-blue" (click)="getCities()">Select City</button>
    <ul class="location-filter" *ngIf="cityList">
     <li *ngFor="let city of cityList">
       {{city}} <input value={{city}} (change)="onCheckChange($event)" type="checkbox" name="selectCity">
     </li>
   </ul>
  </span>
 <button type="submit" value="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

And your `onCheckChange` method would look like this:

```
onCheckChange(event: any)
  {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    if (event.target.checked)
    {
      this.selectedCities.push(event.target.value);
    }
    else
    {
      this.selectedCities = this.selectedCities.filter(x => x !== event.target.value);
    }
  }
```

Take a look at [this](https://angular-hnanj1.stackblitz.io) Stackblitz illustrating this.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference DOM element by using the # selector and viewchild.
In your .ts you can get the element like this:

```
@ViewChild('yourSelector') anyName: Input
```

and then call any function that exists on the element. and in your .html you use the # selector:

```
<input #yourSelector type="checkbox"....
```